# is it possible for command time on Databricks to increase to almost double without changing the cluster specifications? what could be causing that?

Tags: performance, pyspark, cluster-computing, databricks

to store data in s3 bucket form Databricks, I used to write the following:

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("s3://.....")
```

> the code above used to take 3.27 minutes, it takes now 7.37 minutes, using the same
> cluster configuration and the same data.

Comment: look into Spark UI of the job and see where it spent time executing this code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.